# How do I replace this shower drain?

Tags: shower, drain

I guess this one is two questions:

1. Can I replace this shower drain?
2. Assuming I can, how do I go about doing it?

Some background. We've just moved into an older property and are slowly fixing bits of it. The shower seems prone to clogging, and I think this might be down to my wifes long hair getting down the shower drain. The drain itself looks a bit odd to me. It has a raised upper circular dish with a screw through the center that screws into a central pillar within the drain itself. See the images below.

[image: Drain cover removed]
[image: Underside of drain cover]
[image: Drain fitted to shower]

The design is such that you can't stop hair from sliding down the drain, so ideally I'd like to replace the upper "screwed in" bit of the drain with something with a grill or grid that will catch hair. Anyone know how to go about doing this? Google has not been much help.